# Mock dispatch from Redux Thunk as a unit test?

Tags: jestjs, redux-thunk

I have a basic Redux Thunk:

```
export const add = () => async dispatch => {
  const res = await fetch("https://swapi.co/api/people/");
  const res2 = await res.json();
  const people = res2.results;

  return dispatch({
    type: "ADD",
    people
  });
};
```

I need to write a unit test for this. However, my mock appears not to have been called:

```
test("thunk", () => {
  const dispatch = jest.fn(() => {});
  add()(dispatch);
  console.log(dispatch.mock.calls); // result is []
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need mock `fetch` and `res.json()` method too.

`index.ts`:

```js
export const add = () => async dispatch => {
  const res = await fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/');
  const res2 = await res.json();
  const people = res2.results;

  return dispatch({
    type: 'ADD',
    people
  });
};
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { add } from './';

describe('add', () => {
  test('thunk', async () => {
    const mJson = jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce({ results: { name: 'elsa' } });
    window.fetch = jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce({ json: mJson });
    const dispatch = jest.fn();
    await add()(dispatch);
    expect(dispatch).toBeCalledWith({ type: 'ADD', people: { name: 'elsa' } });
    expect(window.fetch).toBeCalledWith('https://swapi.co/api/people/');
    expect(mJson).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58595518/index.spec.ts
  add
    ✓ thunk (9ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.866s, estimated 10s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/58595518